# Can a table name be used as a field for another table?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database

I have three tables Movies, MoviesWatched, Person1....n

```
Movies table:
M_ID, Title, Director, etc..

MovieWatched table:
M_ID, DateWatched, (Person who watched movie)

Person1...n table:
MovieOwned(Same as M_ID), NumberOfViews, ________
```

Basically for each user there will be a separate Person table created that holds the MovieIDs that exist in their movie library. I am trying to find a way to link the MovieWatched table to the Person1...n table. So far, the only way I see is to have a P_ID for each movie in the row. I'm looking for another way because that would make it that each Person table row will always contain the same P_ID.

The alternative would be to have one table that holds all persons. The drawback to that would be that the table would need 1...n columns to hold the movieIDs and there would be multiple columns left NULL.

Each Person table will be unique in the tablename itself so I am wondering if it is possible to refer to a table name as a field in MoviesWatched so that I do not have to repeat the PersonID in the rows for each movie owned.

Comment: Very **BAD** design. Have a single `person` table with a field to identify which person the record belongs to. Then your question becomes moot. As a general rule of thumb, ANY design which calls for mutiple tables based on some other field in a database can be done MUCH easier with a single table and putting that "other field" value as a field into the one table.

Comment: Extremely BAD design.  This would result in a maintenance nightmare and there is simply NO reason to do this.

Comment: My reasoning was to prevent multiple fields being left as NULL. I am pretty new to DB design and I figure if I did it with multiple tables the overall DB would be smaller since there would not be multiple columns for each movie left NULL. With one table the design would be like: P_ID, Movie1.....n = M_ID. Is this still better practice?

Comment: Well the reason I am doing it this way is so that each user can pull up their own individual movie list that consists of movies from the movie table. I need some way of listing what movies each person has in their own personal movie list. A single persons table would contain as many columns as there are rows in the movies table.

Comment: @user2780385 You're on the right track. See my answer for what you should consider. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track with your `MoviesWatched` table: consider that tables in a relational database can represent entities *or relationships*.

You're halfway there by referring to Movies by their ID from other tables. You'll want to do the same for Persons:

```
Movies table:
M_ID, Title, Director, etc..

Person table:
P_ID, Name, Other attributes of an individual person...

MovieWatched table:
M_ID, P_ID, DateWatched

MovieOwned table:
M_ID, P_ID, NumberOfViews
```

Note the latter two tables. A row in each of those tables represents an instance of a *specific person* watching or owning a *specific movie*. Having a relatively small number of rows in the entity tables (representing movies and people) and a relatively large number of rows in the relationship tables (representing each time any person watches or owns any movie) is a natural outcome of the relational model, and database engines like MySQL are designed to support it.

(**Another Note:** technically, a field like NumberOfViews could be *calculated* by counting entries in the MoviesWatched table for a given person and movie, and then correlated with whether or not the person also owns the movie, rather than storing the field on MovieOwned and needing to keep it updated over time. That's the sort of power you get from properly using this model!)

Comment: Awesome! This solves exactly what I am trying to accomplish. Great post.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be describing a many-to-many relationship. This is normally solved using a junction table:

Movies table:
`M_ID, Title, Director, etc...`

Person table:
`P_ID, Name, etc...`

MovieWatched table:
`M_ID, P_ID, DateWatched`

See how we can relate any number of movies to any number of people?  Thus, "many-to-many."

You can apply the same concept to movies owned.

I would also put in referential integrity: constraints that the database will enforce on your data.  In this case, MovieWatched.M_ID should be a foreign key to Movies.M_ID.  Similarly with Person.P_ID.  This will keep your database from having orphan records, or records that might exist in MovieWatched, but not in Person or Movies (imagine deleting a person but not their watched movies).

You could also put a unique constraint on MovieWatched (M_ID, P_ID) if you only wanted to allow each person to view each movie once (this often happens in a junction table but may not make sense for you if you essentially want a log of movies watched).